# a strange sentence in the movie Greyhound (2020)

Tags: meaning-in-context

while explaining ship status is said in the movie:

> We have a five-degree list at starboard,
> and we're down at the stern, but we'll tow all right up to five knots. We have a flap of plate sticking up, scooping in the sea.

What does it mean by the the phrase "scooping in the sea"? what does scooping mean here? is it transitive? and what about sticking up? I'll be thankful so much to everybody helping me.

Comment: A plate of steel, part of the ship's hull, is damaged. It is protruding (sticking up) from the hull so that it directs ([scoops](https://www.lexico.com/definition/scoop)) seawater through a hole into the ship. Not only will the ship take on water, it will cause a drag on the motion of the ship.

Comment: That's very kind of you for answering my question. The verb scoop doesn't have any objects here. could you give me some examples of how to use this verb in a sentence because I don't understand how to use this verb meaning 'direct''? Sorry to intrude.

Comment: I scooped some ice-cream from the tub. The broken plate scooped water from the sea.

Comment: really sorry for talking too much. Why is it said " in the sea 'in the movie not from the sea?

Comment: Scooping up, scooping in... The sea is coming **in**, that's where the preposition belongs, even though the broken plate is **in** the sea. "I scooped in my lottery winnnings" is a different use from "I was rolling in my lottery winnings".

Comment: Thanks so much. May you get to whatever you wishes.

Comment: For the last question, how to distinguish between these sorts of phrasal verbs? is there any criteria standing for that?just like the example you filled me in.' roll in and scooped in''?

Comment: Practice, practice... I don't know of a rule.